# Delete Nav item in grid layout from CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid

After looking for and testing a lot of layouts I picked a very good one but I need to delete the NAV item. I tried but it does not work.

Here is a Codepen with it working untouched
https://codepen.io/familias/pen/WNYQeqQ

In this Codepen you can see header, nav, main, aside and footer. The NAV is in red color, this is the one I need to make disappear. And the main item will get bigger after deleting the NAV item

Here is the HTML code:

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">
    <header>
      this is the header
    </header>
    <nav>
      this red one must die in the CSS code and HTML
    </nav>
    <main>
      this is the main
    </main>
    <aside>
      this is the aside
    </aside>
    <footer>
      this is the footer
    </footer>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
   body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "nav content side"
    "footer footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
    }
    header {
    grid-area: header;
    background: #baffc9;
    height: 100px;
    }
    nav {
    grid-area: nav;
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    background: red;
    }
    main {
    grid-area: content;
    }
    aside {
    grid-area: side;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    background: #ffdfba;
    }
    footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background: #bae1ff;
    height: 100px;
    }
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
    grid-template-areas:
      "header"
      "nav"
      "content"
      "side"
      "footer";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows:
      auto /* Header */
      minmax(75px, auto) /* Nav */
      1fr /* Content */
      minmax(75px, auto) /* Sidebar */
      auto; /* Footer */
      }
      nav,
      aside {
     margin: 0;
     }
     }
```

I tried many ways but I don't know how to code in grid, I am from the old CSS school only. But I am learning

I need to delete in a safe way this Nav item from the CSS code and from the HTML code without damaging the CSS code

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `<nav>` element from the HTML and the `nav` element from the CSS. I would also change the `grid-area` on `main` to auto.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid.php) is a good reference to become familiar with the css grid property.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header header"
        "content content side"
        "footer footer footer";
    grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    height: 100vh;
}
header {
    grid-area: header;
    background: #baffc9;
    height: 100px;
}
main {
    grid-area: auto;
}
aside {
    grid-area: side;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    background: #ffdfba;
}
footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    background: #bae1ff;
    height: 100px;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "content"
            "side"
            "footer";
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows:
            auto /* Header */
            1fr /* Content */
            minmax(75px, auto) /* Sidebar */
            auto; /* Footer */
    }
    aside {
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <header>
                this is the header
            </header>
            <main>
                this is the main
            </main>
            <aside>
                this is the aside
            </aside>
            <footer>
                this is the footer
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: So I must keep all CSS about nav in the CSS ?  "nav content side", grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "nav"
            "content"
            "side"
            "footer";   nav,
    aside {
        margin: 0;
    } ?

Comment: No. You can delete the css for `<nav>` if you delete `<nav>this red one must die in the CSS code and HTML</nav>`.

Comment: Thats a very poor answer, you just deleted the nav markup leaving the entire css code with confusing unneeded code

Comment: @Kamikaza whoops! I completely missed the last one. :)

Comment: how about grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr 200px; ?